# Android Determining whether a Notification from Another App is Pressed when In Current App

Tags: android, notifications, listener

Is there a way to get information whether an notification is pressed when inside an app? For example a user is inside your app A, and then a notification from another app B (e.g. SMS Messenger / Social Media app) is displayed on the top of the screen for a few seconds. There is no desire to block these notifications. But only to determine whether a user has pressed the notification to enter app B.

Comment: Other than perhaps via a `NotificationListenerService` or `AccessibilityService`, this should not be possible, for privacy reasons.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas. But There is a bug (https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=59044) in NotificationListenerService so you cannot receive events from onNotificationPosted or onNotificationReceived. If it were working, it seems from the API you cannot get a callback when the notification is selected. With AccessibilityService you can get an event when a notification comes on screen but not when it is clicked. So unfortunately to answer the question, No, you cannot get information whether a notification is pressed.